# Can anybody put this sentence in a simpler way, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand the phrase "As a guide to the missed opportunity that this represents" in this paragraph:

"**As a guide to the missed opportunity that this represents**, according to international business representatives of the B20 Trade Taskforce the reversal of all of the trade restrictive measures implemented since 2008 could boost global GDP by $423 billion a year and support 9 million jobs."

And by the way, what does "B20 Trade Taskforce" mean? I googled it but I couldn't get any good answer.

[Source](http://www.businessinsider.com/globalisation-is-slowly-dying-2016-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's a very obtusely worded sentence. I'm a native speaker, and that took me a minute.

Very roughly, in this context it means "as an example". In simpler English, that paragraph means (and I'm assuming some stuff about the containing document):

"As an example, this group of important business people say that if we undo all this stupid regulation, we could make a lot more cash."

The B20 is the business wing of the G20, the committee of 20 important economies. http://b20turkey.org/the-b20/